# Different Zooms in different Visual Studio 2019 windows

Tags: visual-studio, zooming

Since I like to work with multiple wide monitors I have different windows of the same solution opened on Visual Studio. That means that different windows of differents Clases are open.
Is there a way to have window A with 120% zoom and window B with 180% and window C with 100%?

I am currently using 2019 version

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a way to achieve this, which is kind of surprising.

Comment: Currently zoom settings change all the windows, not for individual window.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1110124/how-to-zoom-code-in-visual-studio-2022-(nmp-differ